# Snowflake python package requirement size (Lambda limitations 250 MB)

Tags: python, lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to minimize the necessary package size requirements (250) to create a lambda snowflake repository.  yet I keep hitting the threshold, mostly due to snowflake-connector, numpy, pyarrow, and pandas.  Anyone else face similar issues, and did they have success outside of the Docker path?  Want to simplify an AWS layer and zip the packages yet cannot get this to run locally and stay under the 250 MB limitation.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe Lambda isnt the best tool for the use-case then?

Comment: AWS offers many alternative ways to run containers for this reason. https://twitter.com/marknca/status/1433473464178909195?s=19